# MapRoute not working, URL still says page not found?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, maproute

Maybe I am confused here but I am trying to go to http://ryan.local.myappname.com/Order

other things such as /Home work and I checked and found this routes.MapRoute thing and added this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Order", "Order", new { controller = "Order", action = "Index" });
```

But it still says page not found... what the dealio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Order",                                              
            "{controller}/{action}",                           
            new { controller = "Order", action = "Index"}  
        );
```

Comment: sigh: The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running IIS 6?

If so, it has known issues that you'll have to manually resolve:

http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/